# Can't select IL2CPP instead of Mono in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I needed to switch my project from Mono to IL2CPP but it's Grey and I can't select it nor change anything there

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK2h3.jpg)

I tried to change some player settings but It didn't help.

[image][image]
[image][image]
[image]

Comment: You can try installing IL2CPP Module. In Unity Hub, edit the modules of your installation and select IL2CPP for Windows/Mac etc.

Comment: I already have windows build support il2cpp installed, any other ideas?

Comment: What is your platform? Try adding a screenshot of player settings.

Comment: Its android, I attached screenshots to my post by editing

Comment: Then install android il2cpp support.

Comment: There is no such thing aa il2cpp in the modules. There's only Linux IL2CPP and windows IL2CPP

Comment: Try creating a new project with same project settings and check if the issue persists.

Comment: Please make screenshots, not photos with your phone.

Comment: Thank to everyone. I solved it. I just reimported all and now it shows the IL2CPP and can select it. Maybe was just unity's error or something in the project was odd.